# How to clear mysql test database before any tests are run

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js, chai

I am having a very simple **Sails.Js** application containing **Comment** and **Post** models.I am writing few test cases using **Mocha** and **Chai**. The test case are running fine but I am not able to clear the test database before running any tests.

```
/*Comment.js */
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
       comment: {type: 'string'},
       timestamp: {type: 'datetime'}
    }
};
```

The CommentService has a single function that gives all the comments.

```
/*CommentService.js */
module.exports = {
    getAllComments: function () {
      return Comment.find()
    }
};
```

The bootstrap.js file contains following code. I am using **MYSQL** Database. 
What I assume from the DB configuration here in the bootstrap.js that it should truncate all the schemas but not sure why this is not happening.

```
var sails = require('sails');
var _ = require('lodash');

global.chai = require('chai');
global.should = chai.should();

before(function (done) {

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
  this.timeout(10000);

  sails.lift({
    log: {
      level: 'silent'
    },
    hooks: {
      grunt: false
    },
    connections: {
      // Replace the following with whatever suits you.
      testMysql: {
        adapter   : 'sails-mysql',
        host      : 'localhost',
        port      : 3306,
        user      : 'root',
        password  : 'saroj990',
        database  : 'testDB'
      }
    },

    models: {
      connection: 'testMysql',
      migrate: 'drop'
    }
}, function (err, server) {
    if (err) return done(err);
      // here you can load fixtures, etc.
      done(err, sails);
    });
});

after(function (done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  if (sails && _.isFunction(sails.lower)) {
    sails.lower(done);
  }
});
```

The CommentService.spec.js contains following code

```
//CommentService.spec.js
require('../../bootstrap');

describe('The PostService', function () {

    before(function (done) {
      Comment.create({comment: "This is a comment"})
          .then(function(){
              done()
          })
          .catch(function(err){
              done(err);
          });
    });

    it('should return all posts with their comments', function (done) {
    CommentService
      .getAllComments()
      .then(function (comments) {
          comments.should.be.an('array');
          comments.should.have.length(1);
          done();
      })
      .catch(done);
    });
});
```

Any help/pointer is much appreciated.